# How to pass an arrayList between two intent in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I am new in Android and I have a question regarding intent. I want to pass an String ArrayList between two activities by using intent. I have tried this:

```
`
ArrayList<String> playerName = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Game.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Player",playerName);
startActivity(intent);`
```

Then I tried to receive my intent like that:
`

```
 ArrayList<String> playerNameList= new ArrayList<>();
 playerNameList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Player");
 int listSize = playerNameList.size();
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(" ");
 str.append(listSize);
 textView.setText(str);
 StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder(" ");
 str1.append(playerNameList.get(2));
 textView2.setText(str1);`
```

I can get the correct listSize; however I am not able to get any element of my arrayList. I always get the "index(0)" element. I would be really appreciated to any advice and help

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: I think I am able to start intent and send data. Because I can get the size of my arrayList. The problem is accessing to data.

Answer (score 2):

you can easily to by using Gson

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Game.class);
intent.putExtra("Player",new Gson().toJson(playerName));
startActivity(intent);
```

at Game.class

```
ArrayList<String> playerNameList = playerNameList = new ArrayList<>();
String str =  getIntent().getStringExtra("Player");
playerNameList = new Gson().fromJson(str,new TypeToken<ArrayList< String >>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code to add data to ArrayList `playerName`. The code to `putStringArrayListExtra` to Intent and `getStringArrayListExtra` from Intent is correct.