# When Returning an ArrayList of Strings Via Intent I Get null Value

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, null

I am making a mailing app. What I want to do is open list ***chooseContactsActivity*** from ***composeMailActivity***, select some contacts and click add to send them back to `composeMailActivity`. First thing I did was that standard passing between activities where I passed a `string`, and the correct string was passed and recognized in `composeMailActivity`. Then I added `arrayList` of `strings` - of contact ids. In `chooseContactsActivity` it is recognized correctly when debugging, but in the `composeMailActivity` it returns `null`.

Some of the answers I tried include: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791335/how-to-pass-an-arraylist-between-two-intent-in-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453297/passing-arraylist-of-string-arrays-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250339/how-to-pass-arraylistcustomeobject-from-one-activity-to-another), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790499/passing-arraylist-of-objects-between-activities)...

ChooseContactsActivity:

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ArrayList<String> selectedIds = adapter.selectedIds;

            String text = "abc";

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("contacts_added", selectedIds);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
});
```

ComposeMailActivity:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> get_contacts = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("contacts_added");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `data` `Intent` in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`  instead of `getIntent()`
like this

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> get_contacts = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("contacts_added");
        }
```

Comment: That is it, I will accept your answer as soon as I am able to :D

Answer (score 4):

I think try to get "contacts_added" form "data". Instead of calling `getIntent()` try

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> get_contacts = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("contacts_added");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: It works, but I accepted tomtom's answer because he answered a few seconds before, but I voted up. Thank you for your answer

Comment: No problem. Happy that I could able to help you.